# Spans don't respond to the bootstrap responsive properties

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm building this small website : [Website](http://rolandgroza.me/) ; I intend making it responsive in some degree and I'm using Twitter's Bootstrap responsive grid to achieve that.

There is some issue though with the spans, for some reason, I cannot identify, nothing responds to the responsive properties. That is why I would like a new set of eyes to take a look and tell me what am I doing wrong in there because I cannot see it :)

**EDIT :** This is how the HTML looks like :

```
<article class="container">

    <section class="content-view-container">
        <div class="content-view-inner">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span8 clearfix description-details-container">
                    <div class="thumb-container pull-left">
                        <div class="thumb-inner">
                            <img src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/1d7a80504fccf379e4299d7face1bfc3.png">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="headline-container pull-left">
                        <div class="headline-inner">
                            <h1>Roland Groza</h1>
                            <h4>Frontend Developer</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span4 contact-details-container">
                    <a href="tel:0045 29 84 11 04" class="clearfix contact-phone">
                        <span class="pull-left">0045 29 84 11 04</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-phone"></i></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="mailto:info@rolandgroza.me" class="clearfix contact-email">
                        <span class="pull-left">info@rolandgroza.me</span>
                        <span class="pull-right"><i class="icon-airplane"></i></span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="span1">
                    <div class="info-button-container">
                        <div class="info-button-inner"><i class="icon-info"></i></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="span11">
                    <div class="info-description-container">
                        <div class="info-description-inner">
                            <p>Barging in from Romania as a young and truly devoted creator I've landed on the platform of web designing and web development with the purpose to present you my own creation. And I am one hundred percent positive that I can recreate from ashes with just a couple of coding something outstanding. I do possess a multi-facetted-easy-to-dislike personality but my demeanour regarding my work is truly professional and as long as I embark my "merry go round", ideas will always start bursting from nowhere. But here I am trying to improve something, to make your life even more complicated and to reinforce some boundary-pushing style of my own. Complicated means Rebellious, Rebellious means Revolutionary Art. Art means Design.</p>
                            <p>P.S. : Do please take a glimpse of my best work and do not hesitate to contact me for any comments. Believe it or not you might like it. I’ll be honoured to untangle your thoughts :)</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

</article>
```

**EDIT :** As for the CSS, I made a fiddle for it : [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MWAyk/)

Comment: I do understand that the post is to localized but how else should I learn not to do the same mistakes if I don't know what those mistakes are :)

Comment: SO is not to educate one person. Once you fix the website, no-one else can ever benefit from this question again because they can't see the original problem. If you paste the relevant code here it won't be too localized anymore.

Comment: I've read the FAQ :) But this question isn't the only one that is one person specific, there are hundreds of other questions that address specific user issues ... anyways ... if necessary I will delete the post :)

Comment: Yes, and all those should be closed as well. **You don't have to delete if you just fix the question** and copy-paste the relevant code here.

Comment: @Juhana ~ just did that :) Let me know if more code is needed :)

Comment: The css would e pretty helpful too

Comment: @SteveAtkinson ~ the bootstrap specific is available on their website, as for my CSS, there isn't any alterations to the grid :) Also there's a lot of it due to the CSS gradients and transforms ... so I don't want to clutter the post when it can be viewed in the debugger ...

Comment: That's not `css`, it's `Less`. Are you including the Less javascript from http://lesscss.org/ to convert it to actual CSS?  BTW the reason we ask you to post code here rather than rely on a link to your website is that (a) your website may change or even disappear at any time and therefore the question becomes meaningless to future readers looking for an answer to the same or similar question and (b) your website may be malicious and not everyone is wlling to click on your link

Comment: Nope, it's the win app WinLESS that compiles the LESS to CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this close to what you are after http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/53U9N/?

I took your CSS, removed the

```
@import "libraries/bootstrap/bootstrap.less";
```

and instead imported the bootstrap css from a CDN (see the resources list in the fiddle)

I also removed the clearfix class in

```
<div class="span8 clearfix description-details-container">
```

because I'm not sure that you want this there.

Good luck

Comment: So there might be a problem with my bootstrap files or the compiling ? I need the clearfix as there is floating inside that div

Comment: To pinpoint the cause, can you try testing the page using Bootstrap CSS and JS from a CDN? Or share the URL of your actual test page which is causing the problem?