# CSS Rules are Applied Partially

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm developing a small [vCards website](http://rolandgroza.me/). I'm using the [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) LESS files as a base for the responsiveness and the grid.

I had an issue before, the grid wasn't responsive ([Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14110978/spans-dont-respond-to-the-bootstrap-responsive-properties)) and based on the answer I realized that I had to include the `responsive.less` file together with the `bootstrap.less` file in order to get the responsive features.

After having fixed that issue, I still get more weird behavior:

```
<div class="headline-container pull-left">
    <div class="headline-inner">
        <h1>Roland Groza</h1>
        <h4>Frontend Developer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Inspect the DOM and look for the above markup. Now if you start resizing the window down to the least it can go, between `410px` and `514px`, you will notice that the markup will inherit some CSS that is supposed to be applied for the MQ rule `@media (max-width: 480px) { }`, but just a part of it, as Twitter Bootstrap also has some CSS for that rule which is only applied when going beyond `410px` and not above.

Did someone encounter the same behavior before, and if so is there a fix for it?

**EDIT :** The CSS changes that you should look for is the font sizes and margin / padding on the headline :

```
<h1>Roland&nbsp;Groza</h1>
<h4>&lt;&nbsp;Frontend&nbsp;Developer&nbsp;/&gt;</h4>
```

The above text will be the one which behaves a bit weird.

Comment: Are you talking about how the background grid expands to the full screen as the width decreases?

Comment: If you are talking about the two container elements not having the blue background in the same format as the other size you need to look at the .container, .container:before blocks in your other media sizes. After you get below a size(i forget what size) you stop doing the backgrounds the same way.

Comment: Nope, that's a behavior I expect :) Try finding the element I mentioned in the question description and you will see what I'm talking about @zmanc

Comment: Are you using the latest version of twitter bootstrap? I'm looking through the responsive.less files and I don't see any rules for 410px. Maybe try getting the latest files or use jsfiddle to post the compiled .css so people can see what you are actually referring to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are talking about the `<h1>` heading not being responsive, you can use [slabText](http://www.frequency-decoder.com/demo/slabText/) or fix it with an [wrapper](http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/comment/69290/#Comment_69290).

Answer (score 0):

your html is not what you post , it is

```
<figcaption class="headline-container">
<div class="headline-inner">
<h1>Roland&nbsp;Groza</h1>
<h4>&lt;&nbsp;Frontend&nbsp;Developer&nbsp;/&gt;</h4>
</div>
</figcaption>
```

And I can't see any query that states 410px (the one you say should be applied when "going betond 410px ")

Can you comment what is the rule that should be applied and isn't ?

Comment: I have updated the content just a day ago that's why it isn't the same. But the class it's still the same.